# SQL Query for getting single row of similar colum value using group by in subquery

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to get a single column of similar value of column three. this is my query out put now. how can i get this

```
8   31-Jul-2015 10:02 AM    77
8   31-Jul-2015 11:24 AM    77
8   01/Aug/2015 11:04 AM    79
8   03/Aug/2015 10:12 AM    80
8   03/Aug/2015 12:25 PM    80
8   21/Aug/2015 04:32 PM    83
8   22/Aug/2015 05:39 PM    85
8   24/Aug/2015 09:56 AM    86
8   24/Aug/2015 09:59 AM    86
8   24/Aug/2015 09:59 AM    86
```

my query is

```
@employeeId int=8,
    @datefrom date=null,
    @dateto date=null

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     --Insert statements for procedure here


select 
x.employee_Id,
x.punchin,
x.attendanceMasterId

from 
(       
        select atin.punchin,inam.employee_Id,atin.attendanceMasterId

        from dbo.tblAttendanceDetails atin

         left join dbo.tblAttendanceMaster inam on inam.record_Id=atin.attendanceMasterId 

         left join tblEmployeeJobDetails ejd on ejd.recordId=inam.employee_Id

        where ((isnull(@employeeId,0)=0 or ejd.recordId=@employeeId))

) x

END
```

Comment: could you provide your POCO classes, optimally with mapping information? Also, I don't really understand your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: from my above query out put you can see third column values are repeating 86,85 like that. i want to get the every rows, but if it is repeating the third column value
need only first row (i think top 1 of group by the third column)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by concatenating all three columns like :-

```
select (cast(column1 as varchar) +' '+ 
cast(column2 as varchar)+' '+cast(column3 as varchar)) 
as '' from table_name
```

Comment: i want to get the every rows, but if it is repeating the third column value need only first row (i think top 1 of group by the third column)